# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken not call in Swift 4.1 in iOS 11.2

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, push-notification

I am doing all the setting and certificate perfectly but `private func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)`. method not call at all.
If I off Push notification from capability it call `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` but when I on this it never call.

In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` here is my code

```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
            (granted, error) in
            print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
            // 1. Check if permission granted
            guard granted else { return }
            // 2. Attempt registration for remote notifications on the main thread
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        }
}
```

If I am doing something wrong, help. I have worked on this multiple time perfectly but this time , no idea. Help me.

Comment: If that's all you have in your AppDelegate, you certainly won't get a remote notification.  I suggest you do more homework.

Comment: @ElTomato what is missing in didfinishlaunch

Comment: @ElTomato I think you are not getting my query.read it carefully.